# Magento 2 Call product/price/amount/default phtml in product/view/addtocart phtml file?

Tags: magento2, price, addtocart, phtml, default

How Can I call product/price/amount/default.phtml file in product/view/addtocart.phtml in Magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
include_once('product/price/amount/default.phtml');
```